# Seaborn chart converging on same point not visible

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I have a dataframe having two columns- VOL, INVOL and for a particular year, the value are the same. Hence, while plotting in seaborn, I am not able to see the value of the other column when they converge.

For example:
My dataframe is

[image: Dataframe]

When I use seaborn, using the below code

```
f5_test = df5_test.melt('FY', var_name='cols',  value_name='vals')

g = sns.catplot(x="FY", y="vals", hue='cols', data=df5_test, kind='point')
```

the chart is not showing the same point of 0.06.

I tried using pandas plotting, having the same result.[image]

Please advise what I should do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You plot looks legitimate. Two lines perfectly overlap since the data from 2016 to 2018 is exactly the same. I think maybe you can try to plot the two lines separately and add or subtract some small value to one of them to move the line a little bit. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'FY': [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018],
                   'VOL_PCT': [0, 0.08, 0.07, 0.06, 0, 0, 0.06],
                   'INVOL_PC': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.06]})
# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.lineplot(df.FY, df.VOL_PCT)
sns.lineplot(df.FY+.01, df.INVOL_PC-.001)
```

[image]

In addition, given the type of your data, you could also consider using stack plots. For example:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
labels = ['VOL_PCT', 'INVOL_PC']
ax.stackplot(df.FY, df.VOL_PCT, df.INVOL_PC, labels=labels)
ax.legend(loc='upper left');
```

[image]

Ref. [Stackplot](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/stackplot_demo.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very helpful.